# they rather jump around than play clean

Tags: sentence-construction, gerunds

I was watching a concert and I noticed that the **band *'rather' jumps around than (to) play clean***.

Is the sentence in the title grammatically correct or does it need the gerund form of the word 'play' or the base form 'to play' ? And do I need to say ***'they would rather'*** instead of ***'they rather'***  because my fiancee pointed out that I should say that but I object to this since 'would' suggests it's a wish and I'm stating a fact here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom is "would rather (X) than (Y)" where (X) and (Y) are the plain form of the verb - grammatically it is a special case of "would (X)". The meaning is "prefer to (X) rather than (Y)", with no sense of wishing or of a conditional.

So the normal form is certainly "They would rather jump about than play clean".

However, in speech, "they would" become "they'd"; and the 'd' may be barely audible; so you may hear (or think you hear) "They rather jump about ... "

By the way, "play clean" is not an idiom to me, and I can only guess what you might mean by it.

Comment: Thank you! 'Play clean' just means they focus on playing their instruments properly and try to avoid unwanted sound-feedbacks/disruptions.

Comment: I guessed that might be what you meant. But only from context, and only because you contrasted it to "jump around". Otherwise I would have had little idea.

Comment: In British English, an alternative word order would be "the band jumps around rather than plays clean". In your original sentence, the inconsistency between singular "jumps" and plural "play" seems wrong - both singular or both plural would be OK, since a "band" can be considered either as single entity, or as group of individual musicians.

Comment: In that different construction, @alephzero, the verbs are finite, and the question of singular vs plural arises. But in the original construction there needs to be a _would_ (or _'d_)  and the verbs aren't finite and singular vs plural doesn't arise.

Comment: @ColinFine Is there a case where you can use 'to' because In some 'would rather.....than' constructions, it sounds odd to omit it, e.g. in this sentence: 'You'd rather sleep with a pile of clothes on the bed than (to) put it way'. If I omit 'to', I feel strongly inclined to using the gerund 'putting' because it sounds somewhat smoother (but it's probably not right).

Comment: @Chris: I've no doubt that you can find examples with 'to' there, but it feels wrong to me with it, because it breaks the parallellism: 'sleep' without 'to' but 'put' with 'to'.